# Bat script copy

Tags: database, batch-file, copy

Having some issues with a bat script I am building; it is suppose to check a folders modified date and compare it to a source folders modified date and if the dates differ copy down the source folder to the target folder, overwriting the original folder.

```
for %%a in (C:\Source\Target) do set SD=%%~ta
for %%a in (C:\Destination\Target) do set DD=%%~ta
set Y="No Updates Available... Starting Q"
set N="Updating GIS Data..."
pause
if SD==DD (
  echo %Y%
) else (
  echo %N% xcopy /b/v/-y C:\Source\Target C:\Destination
)
```

pause

This is a test script eventually it will be setup to check for updated gis data, update when required, then end on a start QGIS command.

Comment: Type `if "%SD%"=="%DD%"`; `""` avoids trouble with strings containing _spaces_ or empty strings, and the `%%` are required to expand (read) the environment variables (the same you do for `%Y%` and `%N%`)...

Comment: Why would you not just use the `/D` option with `XCOPY`?

Comment: /D didn't work, it might be because I am copying a whole directory or it might be because I am actually copying a file geodatabase (that sometimes acts like a folder and other times acts like a file/directory) or it is as aschipfl indicated and my variables are declared wrong. Also pulling individual files out of a geodatabase and placing them into another geodatabase is asking for trouble, better to copy the whole thing and not just the files that changed. I originally posted this in the GIS Stack Exchange but it was "Off Topic" for GIS apparently and I have not found away to challenge that.

Comment: @TylerVeinot, please tag people with your responses otherwise they will not know you responded to them. You can't have folder and file named the same within the same directory level.  So I am not understanding why you think sometimes it will be a folder and sometimes it would be a file. If you want to make sure it always grabs the attributes for a folder then you would do add a back slash to the end of the path. `for %%a in (C:\Source\Target\) do set SD=%%~ta`

Comment: @Squashman, sorry if that wasn't clear, long and short is I need to copy the whole directory if anything changes, and not individual files. If I copy only the files that change I will corrupt my dataset. When I get a chance I will try the solution aschipfl posted to see if that works and report back.
Thank you for your help

Comment: @TylerVeinot, the modified date for your TARGET folder will not change unless a file has been deleted or added to the TARGET folder.  If a file inside the TARGET folder is modified, it does not change the TARGET folders modified date.

Comment: @Squashman, good point didn't realize that; also didn't consider the fact that whenever the database is accessed it creates a .lock file for every user, this will change the the modified date and initiate an update. I am going to have to find a different variable to base the update on.